# Problems with nVidia gt640 on a desktop

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.10 on a desktop with a nVidia GT 640 that is giving me alot of problems. Everytime I boot, I get a mouse cursor over a blank black screen.

Booting using `nomodeset` gives me full resolution on only one of the monitors, but only over a reduced screen area (it's really weird). I've narrowed it down to the fact that merely setting `acpi=off` in GRUB will enable this.

The strangest part is that I can get it to work. If I totally reinstall the mesa package using `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-glx` and use the default driver (the open source one) then I get a boot where both monitors are recognized at full resolution, no problem. However, once I restart, the same error happens.

Is there a way I can get these monitors to be recognized on the first try, no problem? Thanks.

p.s. I'm dual booting and everything works fine on Windows, so I don't think any of the hardware is faulty (just poorly programmed :. I don't really like windows, however, I prefer Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems with Ubuntu 12.10 and a Nvidia ASUS GT640 graphics card. Trying proprietary 310 Nvidia driver wasn't helping since it makes my desktop dramatically loosing performance.

Then, I thought about switching to the pre-build of Ubuntu 13.04 (got the .iso from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/). So I burnt it and made a fresh install.

The first impression was good, the desktop behaviour with the open-source driver was quite much better than using it with Ubuntu 12.10. 
I decided to try out Steam for Linux. The in-game behaviour was still lacking a lot (Tried TF2). Then I've went to the Ubuntu Software Center application and installed the proprietary, tested 310 Nvidia driver.

Once I restarted the system, everything went Ok for me! Good screen resolution, good desktop behaviour, and surprise! Steam for Linux In-game behaviour quite NICE! playing TF2 with my profile recommended configuration happily! :D

I recommend to give Ubuntu 13.04 the chance! Try it, it worked in my case.

My computer's profile:
CPU: AMD Athlon x64 3.0 Ghz x2 (6000+)
RAM: 4Gb DDR2 667Mhz
GPU: Nvidia ASUS GT640 2Gb

Hope these help you! And I apologyze for my english poor skills ;p